# How can try python working in WPF?

Tags: wpf, browser, ironpython, interactive

Try Python is An interactive Python tutorial running in the browser.
http://www.trypython.org/

But, I want to run it in my Winform or WPF application.

How can I do that?

I konw WPF support WebBrowser, could I use try python by it?

I want to add a iteractive window in my application, not only run ironpython in it.

Answer (score -1):

Try [SharpDevelop](http://www.icsharpcode.net/OpenSource/SD/). It will allow you to create a Winform application in IronPython and compile it to an executable.  You should be able to compile the WPF IronPython example in this IDE.

Comment: sorry for my english.did you ues trypython?

Comment: If you wish to embed IronPython in your application have a look at at the IronPython Cookbook.  The section you are probably after is online at http://www.voidspace.org.uk/ironpython/embedding.shtml and http://www.ironpython.info/index.php/Contents#Embedding

The SourceCodeKind enumerable has an Interactive-Code option which allows you to send partial lines (multiple line statements) to the engine.


The calculator and evaluator examples are what I am looking at to add scripting to my applications.

Comment: But I don't want to embed ironpython, and I want to embed the Ironpython iteractive window with intelligent detection, like "try python".